# Lock a python program following an intrusion

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to develop a python program in tkinter in which if the user does not enter the correct username and / or password more than 5 times, the program locks up and cannot be launched for 24 hours. But I can't figure out how to do it. Can someone point me to a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write the current time of locking into a file, and check if 24 hours have passed since.

Comment: How secure does this need to be? With a normal python program, someone could just edit your code and remove the 24h lock code.

Comment: I finally succeeded, I used the datetime module and a .txt file to record the date of intrusion and that it be checked at each launch

Answer (score -1):

from tkinter import *
from random import *
import datetime

class App:
def **init**(self,user,mdp):
self.user = user
self.mdp = mdp
self.error=0
self.ok=0
self.matrice = 128
self.cle = (7, 3, 55)
self.Entree()
self.fenetre.mainloop()

```
def Entree(self):
    self.fenetre=Tk()
    self.fenetre.title("Fichier")
    self.fenetre.minsize(600,400)
    self.cadre=Frame(self.fenetre)
    file = open("Intrusion.txt", 'r')
    contenu = file.read()
    file2 = open("Date_Intrusion.txt", 'r')
    contenu2 = file2.read()
    a=int(str(contenu2)[0:4]+str(contenu2)[5:7]+str(contenu2)[8:10]+str(contenu2)[11:13]+str(contenu2)[14:16]+str(contenu2)[17:19]+str(contenu2)[20:26])
    contenu3 = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    b=int(str(contenu3)[0:4]+str(contenu3)[5:7]+str(contenu3)[8:10]+str(contenu3)[11:13]+str(contenu3)[14:16]+str(contenu3)[17:19]+str(contenu3)[20:26])
    if b - a >= 100000000000:
        self.intru=Frame(self.fenetre)

        if contenu=="Intrusion":
            self.frame_intru=Frame(self.fenetre)
            expression_intru=Label(self.frame_intru, text = "Intrusion detected",fg='red')
            expression_intru.grid(row=0,column=0)
            self.frame_intru.pack()

        self.frame_a = Frame(self.fenetre)
        expression_a= Label(self.frame_a, text = "Username")
        expression_a.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entree_a = Entry(self.frame_a)
        self.entree_a.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.frame_a.pack()

        self.frame_b = Frame(self.fenetre)
        expression_b= Label(self.frame_b, text = "Password")
        expression_b.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entree_b = Entry(self.frame_b)
        self.entree_b.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.frame_b.pack()

        self.end = Frame(self.fenetre)

        bouton = Button(self.fenetre, text = "Validate", command = self.getResult)
        bouton.pack()
    else :
        self.frame_block = Frame(self.fenetre)
        expression_block= Label(self.frame_block, text = "The device is locked")
        expression_block.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.frame_block.pack()
        but_block = Button(self.fenetre, text = "Leave", command = self.quit)
        but_block.pack()

def Lock(self):
    self.intrusion()
    self.fenetre=Tk()
    self.fenetre.title("File")
    self.fenetre.minsize(600,400)
    self.cadre=Frame(self.fenetre)
    self.frame_e = Frame(self.fenetre)
    expression_e= Label(self.frame_e, text = "The device is locked")
    expression_e.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.frame_e.pack()
    bouton = Button(self.fenetre, text = "Leave", command = self.quit)
    bouton.pack()

def intrusion(self):
    f = open ("Intrusion.txt",'w')
    f.write("Intrusion")
    f.close()
    d = open ("Date_Intrusion.txt",'w')
    d.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    d.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer has formatting problems. Also, some explanatory text would help explain why you did.